# Write Clojure REPL Session to disk

Tags: clojure, read-eval-print-loop

Is it possible to write function and symbol definitions to disk after the end of a repl session (or at any arbitrary moment)? If yes, how to do that?

There is a macro called def-source (or the like), that prints out a definition of function. I suspect  there must be a more general function to write all of the symbols named above to disk from current user-name space..

Comment: Check out gorilla repl.  http://gorilla-repl.org

Comment: Common Lisp has `dribble` [here](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_dribbl.htm#dribble), would that be the kind of thing you're after? A quick google brings up: [dribble](https://github.com/sross/clj-dribble/blob/master/README), though it seems not to have been touched in a while.

Comment: @Peter yes, it's a duplicate. didn't searched for it using the correct title.